# What's the shortest way of making jq read from a variable without using a pipe?

Tags: jq

Let's say I have following bash script:

```bsh
json="$(curl -s "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?lat=-23.513442&lon=-46.384794&zoom=18&format=jsonv2")"
jq '.address.road' <(echo "$json")
```

I'm basically using the Nominatim API to get the name of a road in a specific location... The result is:

```
"Rua Linaria"
```

I'm using process substitution with `<(echo "$json")` in order to use the value of the `$json` variable with `jq`... However, I feel that's not the most straightforward way of doing it. I've tried searching for a parameter on `man jq` but I didn't manage to find what would do that for me. In pseudocode I want something like:

```bsh
jq --getvar "$json" '.address.road'
```

Is there any `jq` parameter that allows me to do that? Or does it only work with files or pipes and using process substitution is the workaround in this case?

Comment: see [Can I pass a string variable to jq not the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47105490/4023950) on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or does it only work with files or pipes and using process substitution is the workaround in this case?

Well, it works with files or standard input; pipes is a way of using standard input and process substitution is a way of using files. You could use heredocs or herestrings for standard input as well.

That said, you can use [`--argjson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq):

```
% foo='{"a": "b"}'
% jq --argjson foo "$foo" -n '$foo.a'
b
```

So, in your case, you could do:

```bash
json="$(curl -s "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?lat=-23.513442&lon=-46.384794&zoom=18&format=jsonv2")"
jq --argjson j "$json" -n '$j.address.road'
```

But to me personally, the most *straightforward* way of doing it would be to pipe `curl` to `jq`:

```
curl -s "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?lat=-23.513442&lon=-46.384794&zoom=18&format=jsonv2" |
  jq '.address.road'
```

Comment: Thanks, in my particular case I was avoiding using the pipe because I need to get multiple parameters from this JSON... So I'd need to use more lines like `postcode="$(echo "$json" | jq '.address.postcode)"`. The option with `jq '.address.postcode' <<< "$json"` from the link on the comments I didn't know and is a straightforward option too...

Comment: Yes, that's a "herestring". Personally, though, I don't see anything wrong with `echo "$json" | jq ...`. It's pretty easy to understand and isn't particularly worse off compared to `jq ... <<<"..."`. No special syntax needed, portable to `sh`.

Comment: Calling `jq` to parse a document several times, and having to store JSON in shell variables seems a bit of a waste. `eval "$(curl ... | jq -r '.address | @sh "postcode=\(.postcode)", @sh "road=\(.road)"')"`.  If `eval` seems bad, just output to a tab-delimited list and read with `IFS=$'\t' read -r postcode road`.